# How to manage one SSIS package for reading dynamic & static file names?

Tags: c#, ssis

I have created one SSIS package for reading files dynamically using variable. 
Now the requirement is: read one file (process one file)
Provided the file name is given from folder. 
So is there any way to manage these 2 conditions in one package? 
Thanks.

Comment: can you please add some details to this question ?  Also, if you already have tried some approach you can mention it.  You should also mention how that SSIS package is expected to work and what challenges you are facing.

Comment: For this, I have used for each loop container and file system task. Provided folder path and used one variable for file names. 

Now requirement is:
Read (process)static file name (if d client want to process particular file). 

So, the same  package should work for reading multiple files and one static file simultaneously. 

So, my question is :how should i manage this in one package? 
Thanks! ! !